# HTML & CSS Vertical align body site on all screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a site where my goals is to display a certain part of my site on all screen sizes. So In my body I have a first container with the logo in it and some intro text and then a second container. I want the first container and let's say 100px of the second container showing. The site has a fullscreen background image and the content slides over it(little parralax effect)

I have tried some stuff with vertical align but doesn't seem to be working or the right way.

I made a little code pen displaying the idea.

```
codepen.io/anon/pen/vGXrbB
```

Anyone has any idea what technique I can use to reach my goal?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center div vertically you need to create "floater" div which and you need to know the height of the div which needs to be centered vertically, check this sample:

```css
html, body {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

#floater {
    position:relative; 
    float:left;
    height:50%; 
    width:100px;
 background-color:blue;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}

#centered {
    position:relative; 
    clear:left;
    height:200px; 
    width:100%; 
    margin:0 auto;
    background:green;
}

#middle {
 text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;                
}
```

```html
<div id="floater">
</div>
<div id="centered">
 <div id="middle">
  text
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend! I have a good idea now how I can realize my goal!

Comment: Your welcome. If it fits your question please mark it as answer.